# Sending php POST request in Swift2 takes too long

Tags: php, ios, post, asynchronous, swift2

I have a app which sends a PHP POST request to my server and should get immediately an answer back. With my "old" function the normal behavior is that I open the app and can see the answer at the moment the view is shown.

```
var answer:String = "" //global
func getAnswer() {
    let URL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://someurl.com/index.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    let postString = "some=POSTMESSAGE"
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response,data,error) in
        self.answer = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest is deprecated in iOS9 and I need to switch to NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest. After implementing the NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest, the answer of my Server is shown after 20 seconds, which is definitely to long. I can even see the my variable is filled immediately with the correct answer, but the tableview doesn't show it immediately, what is wrong here?

```
var answer:String = "" // global
func getAnswer() {
    let URL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://https://someurl.com/index.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    let postString = "some=POSTMESSAGE"
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        let c = NSString(data: data!, encoding: 4) as! String
        self.answer = c
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` is async operation, it is executed on background thread. And all the UI operations must be performed on main thread. When you receive callback from `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` you are still in background thread. Hence you need to do table view reload from main thread. Use following code to do that

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.answer = c
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your UI on the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.answer = c
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
```